# Unable to override values of StartIcon margin in MUI Button example

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the Button in the material UI. I took the example of the Button where there is a start Icon.
However I am unable to override the default margin that comes with the StartIcon CSS
[image]

I tried different things to override it

```
<Button sx={{ '& .MuiButton-startIcon': {marginRight: '0px'}}} startIcon = {settings_slider}> All Filters </Button>

<Button sx={{ root: {'& .MuiButton-startIcon': {marginRight: '0px'}}}} startIcon = {settings_slider}> All Filters </Button>

<Button sx={{ startIcon: {'& .MuiButton-startIcon': {marginRight: '0px'}}}} startIcon = {settings_slider}> All Filters </Button>
```

Nothing worked.

You can find the running example here https://yzbbo5.csb.app/

Comment: there's a good solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72920569/3134778

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem but this way worked for me:

```
<Button sx={{ "& .MuiButton-startIcon": { marginRight: "0px" }}} startIcon={settings_slider}>All Filters</Button>
```

And your question solved my problem at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change it using material UI it might not work. I don't know why but you can use `inline styles` it works and I've tried it.

Here is one example.

```
   <Button style={{marginRight: 20}} variant="outlined" startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}>
```

Sorry if this isn't the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I also observed that "sx" is not working but with "style" i am able to override the styles of endIcon or startIcon

```
<Button startIcon = {<DeleteIcon style={{marginRight: '2px'}} />}> All Filters </Button>
```