# How do we reduce the distance between StartIcon and Text in Button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on React + Material UI. I would like to reduce the distance between StartIcon and Text-Login in Button (Attached Picture as below). Can anyone share how to do that? I tried to change the size to small but nothing changes. My code as below. Thank you,

[image]

```
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          size="small"
          startIcon={<PersonIcon color="buttonwordcolor" />}
        >
          <Typography variant="h6" color="buttonwordcolor.main">
            Log In
          </Typography>
        </Button>
```

Comment: Did you try inspecting the button? If not, Please inspect it and where this space is coming from. Then try giving `margin-inline: 5px' or the number of pixels you want.

Comment: Material UI exposes all it's internal CSS that you can override and customize. It's all very well covered in their documentation. Alternatively you can use the `sx` prop to pass inline styles to a single component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy and fast way would be to give the spacing directly in your icon

```
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      size="small"
      startIcon={<PersonIcon sx={{marginRight: '20px'}} color="buttonwordcolor" />}
    >
      <Typography variant="h6" color="buttonwordcolor.main">
        Log In
      </Typography>
    </Button>
```

Or if you are looking for a more consistent solution so you don't need to do it on every button you can make the change in your theme in your components object, like below. In the example I also inluded changes for the text color, hover font size in case they help more.

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#133676',
      dark: '#2e85d4',
    },    
    ...
  },
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        text: {
          color: '#000',
          '&:hover': {
            background: 'transparent',
            color: '#2e85d4',
          },
        },
        startIcon: {
          marginRight: '4px',
          '& > :nth-of-type(1)': {
            fontSize: '22px',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write **important** or **inline** style on ***Typography*** component to change margin. If margin actually now is 0, then you can make it *negative* number.

But be aware, this is not such a good practice

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, I wanted to find a way to globally adjust the startIcon's right margin. Here's what worked for me in React V18, following the official documentation: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiButton: {
            styleOverrides: {
                startIcon: {
                    marginRight: "4px",
                },
            },
        },
    },
});

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                // your routes or components here
            </ThemeProvider>
        </div>
    );
}
```